# Duplicate Rule across objects

Tags: data, duplicate-management, data.com

I have created a duplicate rule on Contact object and comparing records with the Account object.
I had selected the matching rule as Standard Account matching rule.
Action on Create & Edit: **Allow**     Operation on Create & Edit: **Alert and report both checked**

When I save the duplicate record **with report checked**, all the duplicate and saved record should be added into a **Duplicate Record Set** automatically.

But that is not happening. When i tried with another duplicate rule on **account object and comparing account object records**, it is creating.

So, what is wrong happening?